# Supabase - update user profile from trigger

Tags: triggers, supabase

I have a custom public.userProfiles table where a new entry is created every time a new user signs up.
I would like to use that public.userProfiles table to delete users from my app.
I would not want to expose the updateUser method from Auth admin, since it involves exposing the service_role key, so I’m looking at a trigger on public.userProfiles table instead.
It would update the user.data (set ban_duration) as soon as the user row is accordingly edited in public.userProfiles table.

However, I’m unable to find a function that I could call from a trigger that updates the user profile.
Is there any other alternative and safe approach on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Edge Function for user self-deletion. I've published a [blog post](https://blog.mansueli.com/user-self-deletion-with-supabase) about it.

Here's the code of a function handling such case:

```js
import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.195.0/http/server.ts'
import { createClient } from 'https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js@2'
import { corsHeaders } from '../_shared/cors.ts'

console.log(`Function "user-self-deletion" up and running!`)

serve(async (req: Request) => {
  // This is needed if you're planning to invoke your function from a browser.
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response('ok', { headers: corsHeaders })
  }
  try {
    // Create a Supabase client with the Auth context of the logged in user.
    const supabaseClient = createClient(
      // Supabase API URL - env var exported by default.
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_URL') ?? '',
      // Supabase API ANON KEY - env var exported by default.
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_ANON_KEY') ?? '',
      // Create client with Auth context of the user that called the function.
      // This way your row-level-security (RLS) policies are applied.
      { global: { headers: { Authorization: req.headers.get('Authorization')! } } }
    )
    // Now we can get the session or user object
    const {
      data: { user },
    } = await supabaseClient.auth.getUser()
    // And we can run queries in the context of our authenticated user
    const { data: profiles, error: userError } = await supabaseClient.from('profiles').select('id, avatar_url')
    if (userError) throw userError
    const user_id = profiles[0].id
    const user_avatar = profiles[0].avatar_url
    const supabaseAdmin = createClient(
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_URL') ?? '',
      Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY') ?? ''
    )
    const { data: avatar_deletion, error: avatar_error } = await supabaseAdmin
      .storage
      .from('avatars')
      .remove([user_avatar.name])
    if (avatar_error) throw avatar_error
    console.log("Avatar deleted: " + JSON.stringify(avatar_deletion, null, 2))
    const { data: deletion_data, error: deletion_error } = await supabaseAdmin.auth.admin.deleteUser(user_id)
    if (deletion_error) throw deletion_error
    console.log("User & files deleted user_id: " + user_id)
    return new Response("User deleted: " + JSON.stringify(deletion_data, null, 2), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      status: 400,
    })
  }
})
```